# How can I show Table's TD without text?

Tags: html, css

I want to make an HTML color table to do my school exercise. But I can't make the preceding rows and columns without text in them. Settings them one by one on cell's background color just to them invisible will be much of a burden, so I wanna ask if there's any way to show the table without text? So I can learn this way too, I'm a beginner on HTML btw.

Here's both my HTML & CSS

```css
#table 
  {text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px, solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <style>
  tr, td
    {padding: 5px;}
  </style>
</head>
 <body>
   <table id="table">
     <tr>
       <td bgcolor="ff0000">tilda</td>
       <td>tilda</td>
       <td>tilda</td>
       <td>tilda</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>tilda</td>
       <td>tilda</td>
       <td>tilda</td>
       <td>tilda</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>tilda</td>
       <td>tilda</td>
       <td>tilda</td>
       <td>tilda</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>tilda</td>
       <td>tilda</td>
       <td>tilda</td>
       <td>tilda</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML (not really clean) but you can use like this:

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```